# Is it possible to create a new windows phone 8 project in visual studio 2013 update 2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am using a windows 8.1 machine with visual studio 2013 update 2 installed. I am trying to create a new windows phone 8 project. But visual studio don't ask me about the target OS. It just creates an 8.1 project. Working with my old windows phone 8 project is okay but create a new one.

Any way I can create a new one without installing visual studio 2012?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/04/02/visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc-universal-projects-for-windows-and-windows-phone.aspx

Here they say it is possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try creating new Blank Project (Windows Phone Silverlight) One in the Store Apss -> Windows Phone Apps.

Answer (score 2):

"If you want to create or maintain a Windows Phone 8 version of your Windows Phone Store app, you must install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0. This SDK is an optional component of Visual Studio 2013."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can only target windows phone 8 or windows 8 in class library or portable libraries. You cannot change the target in the phone app project.. Even for class library you will need the to optionally install windows 8 SDK during VS installation.